# Xfce4-terminal, midnight commander, show prompt in title

Tags: prompt, xfce4-terminal

**Issue.** In xfce4-terminal, how can I display actual prompt from terminal in title when midnight commander is running?

Funny is, that when I connect for example via `ssh` to old Centos (`Linux ocms7-app 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64`) and run `mc`, everything is ok, title is changing based on current directory. But on local computer (`Linux local 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu`) it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version [of Xubuntu and XFCE] are you using? It works to get the prompt alias path in the title for me in Xubuntu 19.10. I tested in a live session right now.

Comment: @sudodus `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"`, `Linux local 5.0.0-32-generic #34~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 10 10:36:02 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`, `xfce4-panel 4.12.2 (Xfce 4.12)`.

Comment: I tested with xfce4-panel version 4.14.1 and xfce4-terminal 0.8.8-1. But it works in my Lubuntu 18.04.x LTS with xterm and with lxterminal (I don't want to install xfce4-terminal there because it is my working system.)

Comment: @sudodus Thanks. I'll check some configurations. Quite puzzling me that it works for old Centos server. :/

Comment: Old Centos is well debugged and polished: old tools like `mc` will work well (but some new tools may need features that are not there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just about `mc` configuration, especially `Options > Layout` and check `XTerm window title`.

[image]

Comment: +1; but I think you high-lighted the wrong line in the screenshot ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some corruption in your system, because I tested in an up to date test system of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, where I installed xfce4 and it works to get the prompt alias path in the title for me with this version of xfce4-terminal.

- I suggest that you make a USB boot drive with Xubuntu and try (boot live without installing) how it works in a 'clean system'.
- I think you have added something in your system that stops this from happening, or maybe your system is upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, and what about title when next tab is opened? I updated the question.

Comment: @genderbee, it works as expected for me, with two tabs each tab has the correct title and the window's title is that of the active tab. -- I suggest that you make a USB boot drive with Xubuntu and try (boot live without installing) how it works in a 'clean system'. -- I think you have added something in your system that stops this from happening, or maybe your system is upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @sudosus Hi, thanks. At the end, it was about configuration in mc, especially `XTerm window title`, see my update. How should I close this issue? Can I sign as solved to my question? Thanks.

Comment: @genderbee, If you think my answer was helpful, you can upvote it. If you think it was solving the problem you can accept it, but I think you solved the problem yourself. So I suggest that you move the 'Update2, solved' into an answer and accept that answer (by clicking the tick). You may have to wait for a couple of days before you can accept your own answer.